# Prove that $( X,τ)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$ if and only if $X$ is countable

Tags: general-topology

"Let $(X,τ)$ be a discrete topological space. Prove that $( X,τ)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Bbb R$ if and only if $X$ is countable."

How do I get started on this one? I know that R has both countable and uncountable subspace, and you can only have a homeomorphism if the cardinality is the same. Now sure where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: what subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are discrete?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is countable, you can simply enumerate the elements of $X$ (say, $x_i$) and map $x_i$ to $i \in \mathbb{N}$.  This is (almost tautologically) a bijection, and it's a homeomorphism since $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete.

For the other direction, you need to prove that if $Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable set, then it is not discrete. If $Y$ were uncountable and discrete, then for each $y \in Y$ there exists an open set $U_y$ such that $U_y \cap U_{y'} = \emptyset$ for $y \neq y'$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, each $U_y$ contains an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, say $q_y$, and all these $q_y$ are distinct. But then $\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb R$ has a countable base, so all subspaces of $\Bbb R$ have a countable base too. So if $D$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ that has the discrete topology, any base for $D$ (in the subspace topology) must contain all sets of the form $\{d\}, d \in D$, and so $D$ is at most countable.